# Angular JS dismissing $modalInstance: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, karma-jasmine

Writing a test to test my delete functionality for my app.  I created a mock delete $modal to simulate cancelling/confirming deletion.

```js
  var modalInstanceMock=
       {
        result: {
            then: function(confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
                //Store the callbacks for later when the user clicks on the OK or Cancel button of the dialog
                this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
                this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
            }
        },
        confirmCallBack: function(item){
         return true;
        },
        cancelCallback: function(type){
         return false;
        },
        close: function( item ) {
            //The user clicked OK on the modal dialog, call the stored confirm callback with the selected item
     
            this.result.confirmCallBack( item );
        },
        dismiss: function( type ) {
            //The user clicked cancel on the modal dialog, call the stored cancel callback
    
            this.result.cancelCallback( type );
        }

         
       
    };
```

I do this before each test:

```js
 beforeEach(inject(function($modal) {
    spyOn($modal, 'open').andReturn(modalInstanceMock);
 }));
```

This works perfectly:

```js
 var newRes = scope.deleteCar(car);
 scope.modalInstance.close("ok");
```

However when I try this:

```js
var newRes = scope.deleteCar(car);
 scope.modalInstance.dismiss("ok");
```

I get a Type:error undefined is not a function at Object.modalInstanceMock.dismiss.

Can't understand what is going wrong when close works fine.

Comment: see the ui-bootstrap direcive, How they are using modal. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @Shohel I have and have used it to produce the correct functionality in my app. It is the test that I'm having difficulty with

Answer (score 1):

Initilize in beforeEach,

```
modalInstance = {
        close: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.close'),
        dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.dismiss')
    },
```

and then expect.